# Как запретить запуск копии приложения с помощью std::mutex (std::atomic or std::thread)

Tags: многопоточность, c++11, mutex

Есть WinAPI-решение:

```
HANDLE hMutex = OpenMutexA( MUTEX_ALL_ACCESS, 0, "Application" );

if( !hMutex )
    hMutex = CreateMutexA( 0, 0, "Application" );
else
{
    MessageBoxA( nullptr, "You've been try to execute copy of this program", "Error", 0u );
    CloseHandle( hMutex ); 

    exit( 1 );
}
```

Надо запретить запуск копии приложения с помощью средств C++1*.

Comment: Никто не знает, что ли?(

Comment: Это системозависимая вещь, при чем тут С++ (да и многопточность тоже)?

Comment: Простите, я пока не очень разбираюсь в многопоточности. Просто надо реализовать вышеприведенный код на C++11, если это возможно.