# Почему в следующем куске кода программа завершается аварийно?

Tags: c++, многопоточность

Объясните, пожалуйста:

```
std::mutex test;

if (test.try_lock( ) == true)
    std::cout << "блокировка установлена"    << std::endl;
else
    std::cout << "блокировка не установлена" << std::endl;

test.unlock( ); // теперь разблокируем мьютекс
test.lock( );   // заблокируем его снова

if ( test.try_lock( ) )  //true можно опустить
    std::cout << "блокировка установлена"    << std::endl;
else
    std::cout << "блокировка не установлена" << std::endl;

test.lock( ); // и последнее (заблокируем)
```

Ещё один вопрос. Можно ли создать с помощью этих средств программу, которая не допускает создания копии самой же себя. Я и так, и сяк пробовал, но не получается.

Comment: А на какой строке падает?

Comment: *"Можно ли создать с помощью этих средств программу, которая не допускает создания копии приложения"* -- нельзя.

Comment: Возможно, нельзя отпускать блокировку, если `try_lock` её не взял.

Comment: В самом конце, в test.lock(); // и последнее (заблокируем)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> программа завершается аварийно?

```
$ gcc --version
gcc (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4) 5.4.0 20160609
```

Нормально отрабатывает, не падает. Да и с чего бы ей падать? Смотрите в отладчике, прогоняйте через valgrind, может где-то что-то в окружающем коде влияет.

> Можно ли создать с помощью этих средств программу, которая не допускает создания копии приложения

Нельзя. Ваша программа должна искать уже запущеный экземпляр себя же, и предпринимать какие-то действия в зависимости от результата. Как именно искать - зависит от многих причин, например, от целевой ОС, от ваших задач и т.д.

Из общих механизмов: первый экземпляр программы может создать и залочить какой-то специальный файл. Если при запуске програма не находит этот файл, или не может захватить его, считаем что один экземпляр уже запущен.

Comment: Повторный вызов `lock()` в данном случае не является валидным, см. мой ответ.

Answer (score 7):

Если бы Вы указали [откуда взяли пример](http://ru.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/mutex/try_lock), было бы проще дать верный ответ.

Проблема в том, что вызов `lock` для `std::mutex` в том же потоке нарушает предусловие вызова, если мютекс уже был захвачен:

> *Requires*: If `m` is of type `std::mutex`, `std::timed_mutex`, or `std::shared_timed_mutex`, the calling thread does not own the mutex.

Может возникнуть ошибка:

> — `device_or_resource_busy` — if the mutex is already locked and blocking is not possible.

И еще:

> [*Note*: A program may deadlock if the thread that owns a mutex object calls `lock()` on that object. If the implementation can detect the deadlock, a `resource_deadlock_would_occur` error condition may be observed. —*endnote*]

Это и приводит к аварийному завершению или бесконечной блокировке программы.

---

Предотвращение запуска второй копии программы обеспечивается созданием и получения эксклюзивного доступа к какому-либо ресурсу, который должен быть виден (для проверки наличия блокировки) из разных процессов. В Windows для этого можно использовать [именованные мютексы](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/ms682411(v=vs.85).aspx).

Решить подобную задачу `std` мютексами не представляется возможным, т.к. требуется синхронизация между *процессами*, в то время как обеспечивается только между *потоками*.

Answer (score 2):

В Linux решить вашу задачу ([запуск одной копии приложения](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/644689/232)) можно сделав блокировку собственного исполнимого файла (к счастью, его всегда легко найти в оглавлении */proc/*), неблокирующим вызовом [flock](https://linux.die.net/man/2/flock).

Вот пример кода

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/file.h>
#include <limits.h>

int
main (int ac, char *av[])
{
  char expath[PATH_MAX];
  ssize_t l = readlink("/proc/self/exe", expath, sizeof(expath) - 1);
  if (l > 0) {
    expath[l] = 0;
    int fd = open(expath, O_RDONLY | O_CLOEXEC);
    // printf("open %d %m\n", fd);
    if (flock(fd, LOCK_EX | LOCK_NB))
      perror("flock"), exit(1);
  } else
    perror("readlink"), exit(1);

  puts("Enter>");
  getchar();
}
```

Что непонятно, спрашивайте.

Comment: А если программа запущена из другого каталога, или бинарь имеет другое имя?

Comment: @PinkTux, cимвольный линк /proc/PID/exe всегда указывает на полное имя файла с загрузочным модулем данного (PID) процесса, независимо от места его запуска. А `бинарь имеет другое имя` -- этого я не понимаю. Поясните, какое другое?

Comment: А почему не используется `/proc/self`?

Comment: @PavelMayorov, согласен, так будет лучше (просто я о нем не вспомнил)

Comment: 1) `cp mybin otherbin; ./mybin & ./otherbin` 2) `/opt/bin/mybin & /bin/mybin` (где второе - не ссылка, а копия бинарника)

Comment: @PinkTux, кажется догадался о другом имени бинаря. Вы имели в виду, что пользователь сделал его копию? Тогда, конечно, не будет блокировки. Тогда им надо блокировать какой-то другой общий файл. Я просто показал, что можно блокироваться на том, что всегда существует и как этот файл найти.

Comment: Кстати, у вас в коде еще переполнение буфера (забыли про терминальный ноль) и сравнение беззнаковой переменной с нулем...

Comment: @PavelMayorov, `ssize_t` знаковая, а с терминальным нулем, ну добавьте единичку  к PATH_MAX (и еще немного к 20), если чего-то такого нереального боитесь

Comment: @avp о елки-палки.! Надо ж было так тип назвать... :-)

Comment: @PavelMayorov, с именем типа не ко мне, а с /proc/self/exe я поправил (в самом деле так лучше)